# Adding sections to tableView using coreData

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

in my app the user adds cells to a tableView using coreData. This works quite well. But now I want the table view to have sections.

The viewController in which you add new cells look like:

```
@property (strong) NSManagedObject *travel;
    ...
-(void)viewDidLoad{
            countryName = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                             @"USA", @"England", @"Italy", nil];
    countryLabel.text= [countryName objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:0]];

  } 
    - (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

            [self.travel setValue:countryLabel.text forKey:@"country"];
}
```

and in the viewController which displays the cells in a tableView:

```
       @property (strong) NSMutableArray *travelAll;
  ...
         NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
            NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"position == %@",_positionString];
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Travel"];
            [fetchRequest setPredicate : predicate ];
            self.travelAll = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];  

        [self.tableView reloadData];

        ...

        - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {    NSArray* headers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"USA",@"England","Italy",nil];

            return [headers objectAtIndex:section];
        }


        - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        {
            // Return the number of sections.
            return 3;
        }

        - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {
            return [self.travelAll count];
        }

            - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

            NSManagedObject *travel = [self.travelAll objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        ...
        return cell;
        }
```

But now my tableView I have just this three sections (headers) but I can't add cell to them.
For example: the user selects *USA* for his new cell, so this cell should be displayed in the section *USA*

Comment: Is your cell identifier set in the storyboard?

Comment: @AbdullahShafique yes

Comment: Is the cell id "Cell"? (Just making sure)

Comment: @AbdullahShafique yes, it's just "Cell" because there is just one needed

Answer (score 0):

Your datasource methods are flawed. For example, you are returning the same cell data for each section. There are other problems as well.

It is much better to use a `NSFetchedResultsController`. Start from the Apple templates (you get that if you create a new project and choose "Use Core Data"), that employ the fetched results controller.

Your section design becomes very simple then: it is enough to simply specify the `sectionNameKeyPath` property.

Comment: Hi, it would be great if you can give me a link to a tutorial...I tried a view things but it doesn't work